# The Slot Game Concern

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a slot game.. and I cannot figure out to get the spinner getting the numbers, and then after the spin it would display like: "You won 1,000,000 points!". I cannot figure out how to do this. Could someone help me? It's just a random number spinner (js) and rewards.

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Spinner
<style>
.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white ;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}
</style>
</button>





<script>

function myFunction() {

var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15) + 1);
    

var x = document.createElement("INPUT");            ///Need to break this out of function...Bug 
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");
    x.setAttribute("value", y);//random number will be y
    document.body.appendChild(x);

returnRandom(y);
}


function returnRandom(r){
//window.alert(r);

var result;

switch (r)
            {
               case 1: var result = 'A whopping 15,000,000 points! Great job!';
               break;               
               case 2: var result = 'Awh man.. -500,000 points.';
               break;
               case 3: var result = 'A win! 50,000 points.';
               break;
               case 4: var result = 'A good win! 1,500,000 points.';
               break;
               case 5: var result = 'A bad loss.. -355,555 points.';
               break;
               case 6: var result = 'Nothing! Not bad nor good.';
               break;
               case 7: var result = ' Lucky seven! 77,777,777 points!';
               break;
               case 8: var result = '444,444 points.';
               break;
               case 9: var result = 'Cry me a river! -3,333,333 points';
               break;
               case 10: var result = 'Oh, You won 5,000,000 points!';
               break;
               case 11: var result = 'Oh! Wow! 99,999,999 points!';
               break;
               case 12: var result = 'Meh. -150,000 points.';
               break;
               case 13: var result = 'You earned it, take 3,000,000 points.';
               break;
               case 14: var result = 'You lost. -100,000 points.';
               break;
               case 15: var result = 'You got Fifteen? A big win! 100,000,000 points!';  
               break;

            }
   window.alert(result);

}

</script>
```

Comment: can you show us what you have so far? With nothing to go off it's hard to help.

Comment: The code is there.

Comment: By the way, there's comments in the answer code so you know what I changed to make it work!

Comment: Thanks! It really helped me! @RachelGallen

Comment: @GoogleQuestioner Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks a bit messy. You seem to have the css integrated as style within the body of the text and the script in the body of the text aswell. Are you acquainted with css stylesheets and external javascript files? easily made. But for now, the following code will work. Check out the snippet.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Slot Machine</title>

<style> /*style and script should go in the head section - didn't look like you had them there */
#spin { /*gave the button an id - you could have other buttons*/
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF; /* took out the background color - white on white? how was that going to work? you could put it back in but change the color to #000000;  or something*/
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}
#spinresult{width:29px; color:#000000;}
</style>

<script>

function myFunction() {

var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15) + 1);
var x = document.getElementById("spinresult");           ///put an input element in the body so it didn't keep creating new ones.
    x.setAttribute("type", "number"); //changed text to number
    x.setAttribute("value", y);   //random number is y
    document.body.appendChild(x);

returnRandom(y);
};

function returnRandom(r){
//window.alert(r);

var result;

switch (r)
            {
               case 1: var result = 'A whopping 15,000,000 points! Great job!';
               break;               
               case 2: var result = 'Awh man.. -500,000 points.';
               break;
               case 3: var result = 'A win! 50,000 points.';
               break;
               case 4: var result = 'A good win! 1,500,000 points.';
               break;
               case 5: var result = 'A bad loss.. -355,555 points.';
               break;
               case 6: var result = 'Nothing! Not bad nor good.';
               break;
               case 7: var result = ' Lucky seven! 77,777,777 points!';
               break;
               case 8: var result = '444,444 points.';
               break;
               case 9: var result = 'Cry me a river! -3,333,333 points';
               break;
               case 10: var result = 'Oh, You won 5,000,000 points!';
               break;
               case 11: var result = 'Oh! Wow! 99,999,999 points!';
               break;
               case 12: var result = 'Meh. -150,000 points.';
               break;
               case 13: var result = 'You earned it, take 3,000,000 points.';
               break;
               case 14: var result = 'You lost. -100,000 points.';
               break;
               case 15: var result = 'You got Fifteen? A big win! 100,000,000 points!';  
               break;

            }
   window.alert(result);

};

</script>

</head>

<body>
<button id="spin" onclick="myFunction()">Spinner</button>
<!--<input type="number" id="spinresult">-->      <!---if you unhide this and hide the other input, you'll see the number-->
<input type="number" hidden="true" id="spinresult"> <!--hid the input so you don't see the number-->

</body>
</html>
```

This would be better separated like so:

```js
function calcresult() {

var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15) + 1);
var x = document.getElementById("spinresult");           ///put an input element in the body so it didn't keep creating new ones.
    x.setAttribute("type", "number"); //changed text to number
    x.setAttribute("value", y);   //random number is y
    document.body.appendChild(x);

returnRandom(y);
};

function returnRandom(r){
//window.alert(r);

var result;

switch (r)
            {
               case 1: var result = 'A whopping 15,000,000 points! Great job!';
               break;               
               case 2: var result = 'Awh man.. -500,000 points.';
               break;
               case 3: var result = 'A win! 50,000 points.';
               break;
               case 4: var result = 'A good win! 1,500,000 points.';
               break;
               case 5: var result = 'A bad loss.. -355,555 points.';
               break;
               case 6: var result = 'Nothing! Not bad nor good.';
               break;
               case 7: var result = ' Lucky seven! 77,777,777 points!';
               break;
               case 8: var result = '444,444 points.';
               break;
               case 9: var result = 'Cry me a river! -3,333,333 points';
               break;
               case 10: var result = 'Oh, You won 5,000,000 points!';
               break;
               case 11: var result = 'Oh! Wow! 99,999,999 points!';
               break;
               case 12: var result = 'Meh. -150,000 points.';
               break;
               case 13: var result = 'You earned it, take 3,000,000 points.';
               break;
               case 14: var result = 'You lost. -100,000 points.';
               break;
               case 15: var result = 'You got Fifteen? A big win! 100,000,000 points!';  
               break;

            }
   window.alert(result);

};
```

```css
#spin { /*gave the button an id - you could have other buttons*/
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF; /* took out the background color - white on white? how was that going to work? you could put it back in but change the color to #000000;  or something*/
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}
#spinresult{width:29px; color:#000000;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Slot Machine</title>
</head>
<body>

<button id="spin" onclick="calcresult()">Spinner</button>
<!--<input type="number" id="spinresult">-->      <!---if you unhide this and hide the other input, you'll see the number-->
<input type="number" hidden="true" id="spinresult"> <!--hid the input so you don't see the number-->

</body>
</html>
```

You can save the javascript (even by using notepad-> save as-> all files (with the extension js) and link it in using `<script> </script>` tags
Similar for the css.  (e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file.css"/>` ) Welcome to Stackoverflow!